# logout.php is not working second time

Tags: php

I have one problem with my `logout.php` . Problem is second time logout. For example, a user has two accounts on my website. User loged in with the first account and then he click loged out it is ok. But when he logged in with the second account then he click loged out `logout.php` does not work. Can you help me here please..

Here is my `session.php`

```
<?php
$session_uid=$_SESSION['uid']; 
// Session Private
if(!empty($session_uid))
{
$uid=$session_uid;
$login='1';
}
else if($_GET['username'] || $_GET['msgID'])
{
$uid=$Wall->User_ID($username);
$login='0';
}
else
{
$url=$base_url.'index.php';
header("location:$url");
}

?>
```

And here is `Login.php` code:

```
<?php
ob_start("");
error_reporting(0);
include_once 'includes/db.php';
include_once 'includes/User.php';
session_start();
$session_uid=$_SESSION['uid']; 
if(!empty($session_uid))
{
header("location:main.php");
}

$User = new User();

//Login
$login_error='';
if($_POST['user'] && $_POST['passcode'] )
{
$username=$_POST['user'];
$password=$_POST['passcode'];
if (strlen($username)>0 && strlen($password)>0)
{
$login=$User->User_Login($username,$password);

if($login)
{
$_SESSION['uid']=$login;
header("Location:main.php");
}
else
{
$login_error="<span class='error'>Wrong password or username!</span>";
}
}
}

//Registration
$reg_error='';
if($_POST['email'] && $_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] )
{
$email=$_POST['email'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

if (strlen($username)>0 && strlen($password)>0 && strlen($email) )
{
$reg=$User->User_Registration($username,$password,$email);

if($reg)
{
$_SESSION['uid']=$reg;
header("Location:main.php");
}
else
{
$reg_error="<span class='registererror'>Username or Email is already exists.</span>";
}    
}
}
?>
```

And `logout.php` code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
$_SESSION['uid']=''; 
if(session_destroy())
{
$url=$base_url.'index.php'; 
//header("Location: $url");
echo "<script>window.location='$url'</script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: *Note:* You should probably have `session_start()` in your `session.php` file as I don't see it being included after you call `session_start()` anywhere.

Comment: @Darren brings an interesting point: how is `session.php` used in your code? Is it auto prepended?

Comment: @Darren  when i click `logout.php` it directing me index.php but again, the page redirects to `main.php`

Comment: @MltHty So my question stands; What does `session.php` have to do within this issue as it seems it isn't being used?

Answer (score 1):

Because you decided to do `echo "<script>window.location='$url'</script>";` instead of `header("Location: $url");` your logout.php is being cached in the browser.  So on the second click, its not even hitting the server.

You should do the redirect on the server-side, not in Javascript. If (1) you don't print anything, (2) you only return the location header, (3) you do the redirect regardless of whether session_destroy() returns true or false, then the browser should not cache this page, and you should not have this problem.

Of course the page being redirected to could also have been cached, so set no-cache headers on pages that should be protected by the login so that a cached version will not be displayed by the browser when the user is logged out.

Comment: security related redirects should be done server side, just in case client side has javascript disabled, or any other tricky situation.

Comment: @developerwjk thanks for reply dear. I try it but same problem.

Comment: @developerwjk when i click `logout.php` it directing me index.php but again, the page redirects to `main.php`.

Comment: I think problem is `login.php` codes. only redirects `main.php`